# Injecting object into controller throw an error

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, php-7.2

I have a project in laravel with a model called Teacher.

I have model file , controller with this code.

```
/**
  * @param Teacher $Teacher
  * @return \App\Http\Resources\Teacher
  */
public function show(Teacher $Teacher) : \App\Http\Resources\Teacher
{
    return new \App\Http\Resources\Teacher($Teacher);
}
```

In route file i have this code

```
$prefix = '/api/v2/teachers';

$router->group([
   'prefix' => $prefix,
   'namespace' => 'CarApp',
], function () use ($router) {

$router->get('/{Teacher}', 'TeacherController@show');
$router->get('/', 'TeacherController@list');
```

});

This is the error that i'm receiving when i'm doing get like this.

http://project.local/api/v2/teachers/1

> { "errors": { "type":
>   "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError",
>   "message": "Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\CarApp\TeacherController::show() must be an
>   instance of App\CoursesApp\Teacher, string given", "code": 500 } }

Comment: You need to post the definition of Teacher model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the namespace suggestion of `App\CoursesApp\Teacher` correct in the error or are you looking for a model?

If you are looking for something else, your `use` statement in your controller may be wrong.

If that class `App\CoursesApp\Teacher` is not a model, Laravel cannot load it by primary key and cannot inject it properly meaning it will just pass "1" as a string.